# Control Arrow Keyboard Shortcuts in PyCharm

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

According to the [PyCharm Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) for Mac, Control + Up Arrow and Control + Down Arrow are used to navigate between the previous and next methods.  OSX of course uses these key combos for (Control + Arrow Keys) for navigating between applications.

Is there no solution beside remapping these keys in either OSX or in PyCharm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open "Mission control"
3. Disable that hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

In Mojave 10.14 to disable Ctrl-up arrow and Ctrl-down arrow, go to **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** -> click on **Mission Control** in left panel. **Disable shortcuts** that correspond to Ctrl-up arrow and Ctrl-down arrow (Mission Control and Application Windows).

Control + Up Arrow and Control + Down Arrow should now work in PyCharm